# Adding a delete button for webform attachment fields

Tags: 7, theming, webforms

I have created a structure of field like below within code and not used *webform UI*. The reason of doing this pro-grammatically is because I have hundreds of forms and I wanted to do it once for all.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
                $form['submitted']['file' . $i] = array(
                    '#title' => t('File'),
                    '#type' => 'managed_file',
                    '#description' => t('Please upload a document or image.'),
                    '#default_value' => variable_get('file' . $i, ''),
                    '#weight' => 100,
                );

                $form['submitted']['remove_name'.$i] = array(
                   '#type' => 'submit',
                   '#value' => t('Remove'.$i),
                   //I NEED A WAY TO PASS $i AS ARGUMENT TO THE CALLBACK
                   '#submit' => array('form_remove_attachment'),
                   // Since we are removing a name, don't validate until later.
                   '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
                );
            }
```

And here is the callback:

```
 function form_remove_attachment($i, &$form_state) {
  //dsm($form_state['complete_form']);
  $clicked = explode(' ', $form_state['clicked_button']['#value']);
  //dsm($clicked, 'clicked');
  if ($clicked[1] == $i) {
     unset($form_state['complete_form']['submitted']['file' . $i]);
  }
  // Setting $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE causes the form to be rebuilt again.
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

Now what I need is a *delete button* for each attachment field to allow users to change their mind on regard the attached files. I can add it of course by *JS* but this way the attachments are not eliminated from `$form_state`.

Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: check this link http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58301/webforms-is-it-possible-to-set-a-delete-field-button

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the [examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module.

There is a module with in that called form_example. If you check the 9th example you would get what you are looking. It has an example of adding and removing fields dynamically and the code is well documented.

change value `'#value' => t('Remove'),` to `'#value' => t('Remove' . $i),`

and in function you could get that as given below

```
function form_remove_attachment($i) {
    $clicked = explode(' ', $form_state['clicked_button']['#value']);
   //$clicked[1] would have the value of $i

    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I reupdated the code above, all I need one is a way to pass arguments to the callback. Do you have idea how?

Comment: updated the post with a code snippet you could use

Comment: Good progress, nevertheless how to I remove the markup + field after I place the condition: if ($clicked[1] == $i) {
    unset($form['submitted']['file' . $i]);  //??
}?

Comment: I updated the code, could you please take a look over it?

Comment: How many fields are you going to have?

Comment: I have up to 5 attachments fields (as can be seen in the code)