# Webforms: Is it possible to set a delete field button?

Tags: webforms

As far as I understand there is not possible do delete the field value of file upload fields but rather replacing the field with an empty one.

[image]

1. Is it possible to add this button using JS and thus delete the text path inside the field without refreshing the page (PLAIN SIMPLE)? Otherwise I am afraid i need to use a php solution with page refresh.
2. If not is it possible for 'Delete' to emulate the 'Browse' button? I mean when hitting 'Delete' to actually browse for another file?

ps. I know webforms are using their own implementation but I am force to find another solution

Comment: Just a note-- I would consider calling such an option "remove" instead of "delete."  Novice computer users may think that "delete" refers to deleting the file on their actual computer.

Comment: Good point Patrick. Or maybe 'replace'

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do that via JS

Answer (score 0):

This link seems to have some solution. [Clear upload file input field with jQuery](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/clear-upload-file-input-field-jquery/)

The relevant js is given below.

> The HTML of any element can be reset with jQuery using the following
>   function and passing in the id of the element's parent. This will
>   reset the HTML within the parent to its original state; it will lose
>   any binding you'd added after the DOM was loaded (such as adding an
>   event handler in $(document).ready). Here's the Javascript for doing
>   this:

```
function reset_html(id) {
    $('#'+id).html($('#'+id).html());
}
```

> In $(document).ready we can now add a div around every  element with a clear button, binding a function to it
>   which will reset the HTML of the div like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var file_input_index = 0;
    $('input[type=file]').each(function() {
        file_input_index++;
        $(this).wrap('<div id="file_input_container_'+file_input_index+'"></div>');
        $(this).after('<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="reset_html(\'file_input_container_'+file_input_index+'\')" />');
    });

});
```

Note : I have not tested this out myself.